# Graphql Typecheck on redux like events

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm implementing a graphql server over some existing REST api using apollo-server.

There is and endpoint returning a list of redux-like events, where Hi have a `type` and a `payload`.
`type` is a string and `payload` is an object. e.g.

```
[
   {
      type:"joined"
      from:"member1"
      payload:{
        received_events:"1518377870416"
        invited_by:"member2"
      }    
   },   
   {
      type:"text"
      from:"member1"
      payload:{
        test_string:"hello"
      }    
   }
 ]
```

What I need to check is the following:

1) `type` is an enum `joined|text`

2) `from` is a String

3) if `type == joined` then the `payload` should contain `received_events` and `invited_by`, if `type == text` then `payload` should contain `test_string`

What is the best way to do it? I'm looking at the scalar , and Union, but I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to inject the type from your event type into the payload object. It can then be used inside the `__resolveType` resolver for your union. A simple example:

```
const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    events: [Event]
  }
  type Event {
    type: String
    payload: Payload
  }
  union Payload = Text | Joined
  type Text {
    test_string: String
  }
  type Joined {
    received_events: String
    invited_by: String
  }
`;

// Since your type names and the specified types are different, we
// need to map them (resolveType needs to return the exact name)
const typesMap = {
  text: 'Text',
  joined: 'Joined'
}

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    events: (root, args, context) => {
      return [
        { type: 'text', payload: { test_string: 'Foo' } }
      ];
    },
  },
  // We can use the resolver for the payload field to inject the type
  // from the parent object into the payload object
  Event: {
    payload: (obj) => Object.assign({ type: obj.type }, obj.payload)
  },
  // The type can then be referenced inside resolveType
  Payload: {
    __resolveType: (obj) => typesMap[obj.type]
  }
};
```